# handling blur with double arrow functions in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to understand why the tutorial I've been following showed me this way of checking "blur" in the input field below. I tried to rewrite the method out without the currying and seems to be impossible. Is someone experienced in React / JS able to help explain what is happening? I understand the basic currying like the classic example of:

const multiply = (a)=> (b)=> a*b then.. multiply(5)(5)

but I can't understand why this also works other than the fact that I do not need to "bind" with "this" like other methods I've created in the component itself. Looking to understand this better and so far no materials out in the wild can make clear of what is happening.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, Button, Col, FormFeedback } from 'reactstrap';

class RegistrationForm extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        //1
        this.state = {
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            userName: '',
            phoneNum: '',
            email: '',
            agree: false,
            touched: {
                firstName: false,
                lastName: false,
                userName: false,
                phoneNum: false,
                email: false
            
            }
        }

        //3
        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

 ...

handleSubmit(event){
        console.log("Current state is: " + JSON.stringify(this.state));
        alert("Current state is: " + JSON.stringify(this.state));

        event.preventDefault();
    }

    **handleBlur = (property) => () => {
        this.setState({
            touched: {...this.state.touched, [property]:true}
        })
    }**
    
...
    render(){

        //Display "state" from "check" method
        const errors = this.check(this.state.firstName, this.state.lastName, this.state.userName, this.state.phoneNum, this.state.email);

        return(
            <div className="row row-content">
                <div className="col-12 mt-3">
                    <h2>Register for an Account & Stay Updated!</h2>
                    <hr />
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-10">

                    <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <FormGroup row>
                            <Label htmlFor="firstName" md={2}>First Name</Label>
                            <Col md={6}>
                                <Input
                                    type="text"
                                    id="firstName"
                                    placeholder='First Name'
                                    name="firstName"
                                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                    onBlur={this.handleBlur("firstName")}
                                    invalid={errors.firstName}
                                    value={this.state.firstName}                                    
                                />
                                <FormFeedback>{errors.firstName}</FormFeedback>
                            </Col>
                        </FormGroup>
                     
                      ...
                        
                    </Form>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
    
}


class Register extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="container">
                <RegistrationForm />
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default Register;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things happening here. The function is curried and an arrow function.

The arow function is why `this` is already bound from the context where the function is created. Therefore we can call `this.setState`.

The other thing is the currying. `onBlur` expects to be given a function, lets call it `fn`. And will call this function when you leave the input, probably with an event like `fn(event)`. But we also want to give our function the string 'firstName' and to give a function somthing means to call it, so we return a function that we then can give to `onBlur`.

You could recreate the currying part like this

```
handleBlur(property) {
  return function() {
    // this would be the same point where
    // this.setState is called
    // but this is not bound here
  }
}
```

The handleBlur function we call during rendering. The inner function is called as part of the event actually happening. And we use arrow functions because it is easier to write and we bind `this` to the context we would expect.

Did this help you understand it a little bit more?

Edit Answer to comment:

Yes the bind has to happen to the inner function, because we want to use `this` in the inner function.

You could off course use a simple function like this:

```
handleBlurFirstName() {
  this.setState({
    touched: {...this.state.touched, firstName:true}
  })
}
```

But now we have to write a function for every property we want to handle and have to bind it in the constructor. Currying is a really useful concept.

Comment: Hi Ian, Thanks for the info! I wrote out your normal function way it seems like the bind now happens after the inner return rather than within the component like the other binds for the other methods. I guess now my other question, would be how come I cannot write this without the inner return and just bind it like the others? I find that very strange.

`
 handleBlur(property){
        return function(){
            this.setState(
                {
                    touched: {...this.state.touched, [property]:true}
                }
            )
        }.bind(this)
    }
`

Answer (score 0):

Either call the handler with your identifier `(firstName)` and return a function dealing with the event itself, visually hiding away the currying that's happening or your catch the event right there where it happens and pass it to the handler dealing with `(lastName)(e)`

I think the seconds approach is a bit clearer to read and understand :)

```
  handleInputChange = input => console.log(input.target.value);
  handleBlur = key => blurEvent => this.setState({ [key]: blurEvent.target.value })
  submit = () => console.table(this.state)

  render = () => (
    <div className="App">

      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder='First Name'
        name="firstName"
        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        onBlur={this.handleBlur('firstName')}
      />

      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder='Last Name'
        name="lastName"
        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        onBlur={e => this.handleBlur('lastName')(e)}
      />

      <button onClick={this.submit}>submit</button>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Your way to call handleBlur is a good explanation, but not good style. If you call it all together why not call `this.handleBlur('firstName', e)`?

Comment: wanted to take the chance to focus on the concept of currying, which I rarely use for exactly your point - style

Answer (score 0):

Being direct:

1. the key word **this** in arrow functions are a **special** case, it IS NOT because of the currying that you don't need bind the **this** *but* because of the arrow function.
2. currying there will NOT help on your case that could be simplified to

   ```
   handleBlur = (e, property) => {
            this.setState({
                touched: {...this.state.touched, [property]:true}
            })
         }
   ```

and then upon invocation

```
   <input
          onBlur={e => this.handleBlur(e,'lastName')}
      />
```

What the tutorial is trying to avoid is having to be verbose (and you are not doing anyway), so using currying you would be having:

```
  <input
          onBlur={this.handleBlur('lastName')} //that it will return ANOTHER function
      />
```